# python: use tuples to re-arrange the contents of a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am a python beginner. Recently I saw this snippet of code:

```
>>> words = ['I', 'turned', 'off', 'the', 'spectroroute']
>>> words[2], words[3], words[4] = words[3], words[4], words[2]
>>> words
['I', 'turned', 'the', 'spectroroute', 'off']
```

I am confused about the 2nd line. It seems tuples are used but I don't understand why the sequence of the list is changed to the result?

It looks like the 2nd line is doing this:

```
>>> tmp = words[2]
>>> words[2] = words[3]
>>> words[3] = words[4]
>>> words[4] = tmp
```

My question is: why does the code in 2nd line change the list as the result?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look up "tuple assignment" in the Python reference of your choice.

Comment: Tuples *are* used. The `,` character defines a tuple, the parens are just for clarity and precedence when needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty much correct. Its creating a tuple on the right side (in memory) and then unpacking its values into the original list, thus overwriting the previous indexes. Thats why you dont need a tmp variable, since its happening in memory.

Its similar to this concept:

```
a, b, c = (1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: so does that mean it is similar with this: words[0],words[1],words[2],words[3],words[4]=(words[2], words[3], words[4] = words[3], words[4], words[2])? BUt why it is not like this:words[0],words[1],words[2],words[3],words[4]=(words[0], words[1], words[3], words[4], words[2]) ?

Comment: That first example in your comment is a syntax error, so no its not correct. Your second example is technically equivalent yes. But its unnecessary to set the first and second indexes of the list equal to their original value. You are only modifying element inside of the list at different indices. `words` is a list container. It contains 5 elements which can be accesses and reassigned via their 0-4 index numbers. Also keep in mind that the `words` list object has never become any new object the entire time. Only its contents have changed.

Answer (score 2):

List is a mutable data structure. `words[2] = 'foobar'` will change the third element in the list to `'foobar'`. In

```
>>> words[2], words[3], words[4] = words[3], words[4], words[2]
```

the right side is evaluated first and the resulting strings are assigned to various positions in the list, thereby changing it.